# Rebind a variable to a different type while used in the `match` declaration

Tags: rust, ownership

I am writing Rust code with a typestate pattern to create an API and a CLI for it.

I have a struct `VendingMachine<S>` where `S` is a ZST representing my current state (e.g. `VendingMachine<Start>`,`VendingMachine<Payment>`,`VendingMachine<Checkout>` etc.)

I want to have my vending machine to run in a loop and match each state to some code:

```rust
let mut machine = VendingMachine::new::<Start>(/*...*/);
loop {
    match machine.state {
        Start => {/* do something and then change the type of `machine` to VendingMachine<Payment> using some transitioning method */},
        Payment => {/* do something else and then change the type of `machine` to VendingMachine<Checkout> using some other transitioning method */},
        ...
    }
}
```

However, the compiler rejects this code - if I rebind `machine` in a match's arm to the result of a transition like this:

```rust
let machine = machine.to_payment();
```

where `.to_payment()` has this signature:

```rust
fn to_payment(self) -> VendingMachine<Payment>
```

Then I get the "use of moved value: `machine.state`" error because "`machine` moved due to this [to_payment()] method call, in previous iteration of loop"

How do I implement the behaviour I need?

Comment: Why would you do that instead of having an enum? It doesn't really make sense to me

Comment: Typestate is a compile-time concept, whereas match is a runtime concept. You can't match on types, and you can't change the type of a binding. If you want to have states at runtime, use an enum.

Comment: I want to have compile-time guarantees over the methods I am using but still have the ability to match those states. Enums won't work because they will allow (or, rather, not explicitly prohibit) improper state transitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rust is a statically typed language, which means that there is no way to change the type of a variable at runtime. It is possible to hide (or *shadow*) a variable by creating a new variable of the same name:

```
let a: i32 = 42;
let a: String = "foo".to_string();
```

but these are *two different variables* and the first one still exists after the second one has been created, as evidenced here:

```
let a: i32 = 42;
let p = &a;
let a: String = "foo".to_string();
println!("{}", a);    // Prints "foo"
println!("{}", p);    // Prints "42"
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=03bb7cce86e33d230e741691fa05a6af)

The original `a` still exists and can still be accessed indirectly through references even after the second one has been created.

For your use case, if you don't want to use an `enum` to prevent invalid state transitions, you can use a trait object instead:

```
use std::fmt::Debug;

trait State: Debug {
    fn process (self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State>;
    fn is_finished (&self) -> bool { false }
}

#[derive (Debug)]
struct Start {}
impl State for Start {
    fn process (self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State> {
        /* Do something then move to the next state */
        Box::new (InProgress {})
    }
}

#[derive (Debug)]
struct InProgress {}
impl State for InProgress {
    fn process (self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State> {
        /* Do something then move to the next state */
        Box::new (Done {})
    }
}

#[derive (Debug)]
struct Done {}
impl State for Done {
    fn process (self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State> {
        self
    }
    fn is_finished (&self) -> bool { true }
}

fn main() {
    let mut s: Box::<dyn State> = Box::new (Start {});
    while !s.is_finished() {
        println!("Current state: {:?}", s);
        s = s.process();
        println!("Moved to state: {:?}", s);
    }
    println!("Final state: {:?}", s);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5ad42488033aed727c4165bf27d72968)

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to change the type of a binding, this is impossible in Rust because after compilation all types are forgotten and if the type was all that's different, then you can't distinguish `VendingMachine<Start>` from `VendingMachine<Payment>`. To be able to separate them you have to use something that can be distinguished at runtime like an enum.